# Resharper warning code heuristically unreachable

Tags: c#, resharper

I am having below code and wondering why else part is unreachable as per resharper.

```
private bool SomeMEthod(some parameter)
{
    bool status = false; 
    var someCollection = _entity.CustomerPaymentStatus.Where(record => record.CustomerPaymentId == paymentId && record.CurrentRecord == true);
    if (someCollection != null)
    {
        var receivedPayment = someCollection.FirstOrDefault();
        /*some code to save data into DB*/
        status = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Some code here to log failure scenario

        //here Resharper giving me warning
        //code is heuristically unreachable
    }
    return status;
}
```

I have checked couple of post but not clear like [Code is heuristically unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532509/code-is-heuristically-unreachable)

Any Thought please.

Comment: `Where` should never return `null` but might return an empty sequence, so your `if` condition will always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Where()` never returns null, but always returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IQueryable<T>`. The enumerable might have 0 items, but it's still a non-null enumerable.

Comment: And if `_entity.CustomerPaymentStatus` is null, then an exception will be thrown and `else` won't be reached either

Comment: @KooKiz: yes, of course. But a `NullReferenceException` is a completely different problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

The Linq `Where` query will return an empty `IEnumerable` if no matching records are found, so it is highly unlikly that `someCollection` will ever be `null` - although ReSharper does not seem to be completly sure about it.

Also see [MSDN Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming _entity is a DbContext, then Where always returns an IQueryable object.

```
 IQueryable<T> someCollection = _entity.CustomerPaymentStatus.Where(...);
```

That IQueryable object is never null (otherwise you wouldn't be able to query it).

Testing that object for null doe not execute the query. So

```
 if (someCollection != null)
```

is the same as

```
 if (true)
```